# Angular: Add .active Class Based on Current State

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to add an `.active` class to my navigation tabs based on the current state, but because the state has an `:id`, it's adding that class of `active` to multiple tabs.

My state looks like so:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('genre', {
      url: "/movie/genre/:id",
      templateUrl: "views/movie/genre.html",
  });
```

And I'm using `ui-sref` and `ui-sref-active` on my markup like this:

```
<li ui-sref="genre" ui-sref-active="active">
    <a href="#/movie/genre/horror">Horror</a>
</li>
<li ui-sref="genre" ui-sref-active="active">
    <a href="#/movie/genre/romance">Horror</a>
</li>
...
```

So despite being on `site.com/movie/genre/horror`, I'm getting the `.active` class on both tabs, rather than just the horror page.

Any help with this is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class is applied to your active state. Your state is 'genre', which is active for both your ui-sref attributes.

I made a plunkr which should work for you [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GWDOJ5bAwtnUPmMvy0aw?p=preview).

```
<li ui-sref-active="active">
  <a ui-sref="genre({id: 'horror'})">Horror</a>
</li>
<li ui-sref-active="active">
  <a ui-sref="genre({id: 'romance'})">romance</a>
</li>
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `ui-sref` on the `li`. It's just needed on the anchor.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I didn't expect the class to be applied to an Element being the parent of an element with the ui-sref directive. I changed that in the answer and the plunkr.

Comment: Perfect @PaulPodlech. Just what I was looking for. Thanks for that too Matt!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `href`, you have to use ui-router states for navigation. In this case you have to pass arguments in your `ui-sref`. And just get rid of href.

```
ui-sref="genre({id:'horror'})"
```